# Static ARP entry disappears on restart in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, arp

I used the command line "arp -s IP MAC" command to set a static ARP entry on Windows Server 2003. When I ran "arp -a" it was there as a "static" entry. When I restart, it is gone. Is there some file somewhere like lmhosts where I can make this absolutely permanent?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is already support for persistent configuration of ARP entries. However, you should be able to create a boot script that does that every time.

In Group Policy, go to Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts, add a startup script.

Answer (score 1):

don't need to be in a domain. local group policy can do, or startup script. however, I found even if log off, the static entry will be gone

Answer (score 0):

I had a Windows Server 2003 which wasn't in a domain, so the above answer didn't apply to me, although it does work for a box in an AD. The below Autoexecnt.bat script worked for me (and works in XP, too):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243486